# jQuery validate display error message in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am new with jQuery validation and learing so I don't have any idea about this. Now I am using [jQuery Validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) and want to display error message inside div element. I have created div for every error message.

For example I have Name input field and want to display error message inside `nameError` div.

```
<div>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id='name' name="name" value="" />
</div>
<div id="nameError">
    <!-- Display Name Error Here  -->
</div>
```

Is it possible for jQuery Validation Plugin? I have no idea that why I am posting here to get help from you.

**MY  JQUERY CODE IS:**

```
$(function () {
    $.validator.addMethod("regex", function (value, element, regexpr) {
        return regexpr.test(value);
    }, "Please enter a valid name.");

    $("#myForm").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                regex: /^[A-Za-z]+$/
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[MY JSFIIDLE](http://goo.gl/R1Ga0R)

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried reading the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may add a check in errorPlacement handler like below:
Please note that errorPlacement function is called for each error, if you need more handling on error message, please check for [invalidHandler](http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/plugin/)

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (element.attr("name") == "name" )  //Id of input field
            error.appendTo('#nameError');
        if (element.attr("name") == "anotherInputField" )  //Id of input field
            error.appendTo('#anotherInputFieldError');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a quick sample: http://jsfiddle.net/4PuJL/7/

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo('#nameError');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi your code is good but have one issue. If I add one more filed then both error displaying error in one div. Not displaying to their div. check this updated fiddle. `http://jsfiddle.net/4PuJL/14/` I hope your understand.

Answer (score 2):

check the following link

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chetandoke/EgQE3/)

HTML :

```
<form>
    <input type="text" required pattern="/^[A-Za-z]+$/" >
        <input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
```